# Terratest Getting Error For Using Count With Terraform Creating EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, count, terraform, terratest

I'm getting an error by Terratest testing provisioned EC2 instances using Terraform, I'm using count to create multiple instances and seems that function (GetPublicIpOfEc2Instance) is confused when returning multiple instance ids, is there a way to make it accept multiple values?

```
--- FAIL: TestRecourcesProvisioning (295.89s)
    ec2.go:121: 
                Error Trace:    ec2.go:121
                                                        flugel_test.go:50
                Error:          Received unexpected error:
                                InvalidInstanceID.Malformed: Invalid id: "[i-0d1e09244e6bdb*** i-0257c214b3242c***]"
                                        status code: 400, request id: ***-8c64-449f-b830-***
                Test:           TestRecourcesProvisioning
FAIL
FAIL    command-line-arguments  295.909s
FAIL
```

Terratest code:

```
package test

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "testing"

    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/aws"
    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/random"
    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestRecourcesProvisioning(f *testing.T) {
    f.Parallel()
    // Specify A Region And Names For Resourses For Provisioning
    approvedRegions := []string{"us-west-1"}
    awsRegion := aws.GetRandomRegion(f, approvedRegions, nil)
    expectedNameIns := fmt.Sprintf("ex-%s", random.UniqueId())
    expectedBucket_name := fmt.Sprintf("ex-%s", strings.ToLower(random.UniqueId()))

    terraformOptions := &terraform.Options{
        // The Path To Terrafom Code
        TerraformDir: "../",

        // Variables Will Be Passed To Terraform Code
        Vars: map[string]interface{}{
            "instance_name": expectedNameIns,
            "s3_name":       expectedBucket_name,
            "lb_name":       fmt.Sprintf("ex-%s", random.UniqueId()),
            "tg_name":       fmt.Sprintf("ex-%s", random.UniqueId()),
            "bucket_name":   fmt.Sprintf("ex-%s", strings.ToLower(random.UniqueId())),
        },
    }
    defer terraform.Destroy(f, terraformOptions)

    terraform.InitAndApply(f, terraformOptions)
    actualInstanceId := terraform.Output(f, terraformOptions, "instance_id")
    actualPublicIP := terraform.Output(f, terraformOptions, "instance_public_ip")
    actualBucketId := terraform.Output(f, terraformOptions, "bucket_id")
    albDNS := terraform.Output(f, terraformOptions, "ex_lb_dns")

    tagName := "Name"

    exptectedPublicIP := aws.GetPublicIpOfEc2Instance(f, actualInstanceId, awsRegion)
    expectedBucketID := aws.FindS3BucketWithTag(f, awsRegion, tagName, expectedBucket_name)

    url := fmt.Sprintf("http://%s", albDNS)

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    
    sb := string(body)
    log.Printf(sb)

    assert.Equal(f, actualPublicIP, exptectedPublicIP)
    assert.Equal(f, expectedBucketID, actualBucketId)
    assert.Contains(f, sb, "Hello World!")

}
```

Terraform code:

```
resource "aws_instance" "ex_ec2" {
ami                         = var.ami_id
instance_type               = "t2.micro"
key_name                    = "ex"
subnet_id                   = "${element(aws_subnet.ex_subnet.*.id, count.index)}"
associate_public_ip_address = true
security_groups             = [aws_security_group.ec2_sg.id]
count                       = 2
user_data                   = file("userdata.sh")

tags = {
    Name  = var.instance_name
    Owner = var.owner
}
```

Comment: We need to see the terratest code - regardless, no get public IP of EC2 instance wokrs on 1 instance, not more than 1

Comment: I added terratest code, Is there an alternative function to test multiple instances?

Comment: If your TF output is returning a list of instance IDs, then you need to treat that as a list or slice in Go and iteratively invoke the `aws.GetPublicIpOfEc2Instance` function.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I tried to treat it as a list I got this error (cannot use actualInstanceId (type []string) as type string in argument to "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/aws".GetPublicIpOfEc2Instance) seems as Ermiya Eskandary mentioned the function is only accepts a single value.

Comment: Yes that is why I made my suggestion; it will move you forward if you implement it.